# Set Focus to Form

Tags: c#, .net, console, console-application

My `c#` `console application` opens a `login form` in which user enters login information, the problem is that when this `login form` opens `focus` is still set to `console application` even though `focus` should be set on `login form`. I've tried using both the `Focus()` & `Activate()` functions with out any luck. Here is an example of how I've tried to set `focus` away from my `console application` and set `focus` to my  `login form`:

```
static void StartLoginForm()
{
        Form frm = new Form();
        frm.ShowDialog();
        frm.Focus();//Didn't work for me
        frm.Activate();//Also didn't work for me
}
```

What am i doing wrong? Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Thank you for your time.

Comment: ShowDialog is a modal call. It means that the call doesn't return until you close the form. So when you call Focus or Activate the form is no more on screen

Comment: @Steve Ohh, that makes sense. I've tried using Show() but that seems to just close the Login Form as soon as it opens :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
static void StartLoginForm()
{
    Form frm = new Form();
    frm.Show();
    frm.Activate();
    Application.Run(frm);
}
```

Comment: I'am glad to hear it! Thank you too :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to **focus first then show the form** ?

```
static void StartLoginForm()
{
        Form frm = new Form();
        frm.Focus();
        frm.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that doesn't seem to work either :(

Comment: Application.OpenForms[frm.Name].Focus(); seems to cause a An unhandled exception. Could this be caused because I'm using frm.ShowDialog(); to display the form?

Comment: That's weird because I've set frm.Name = "TestingForm";
:/

Comment: :-( you are right.. the exception is because the form is not opened yet !